# Is there Any OCR program that can handle non-Latin characters?

Tags: software-rec, ocr

I'm looking for an OCR program that can work with hebrew characters. I'm open to using something on Mac or PC, but it needs to be a reliable program.

What are my options?

Comment: +1: Very interesting question, I'd love to see this answered.

Comment: @MarkSzymanski - Thanks! (Initial Googling leads to some interesting results, but nothing has been tested yet.)

Answer (score 3):

[Abbyy Fine Reader](http://www.abbyyusa.com/finereader/) is a very powerful OCR program that can work with Hebrew characters.

> ABBYY FineReader 10 is a comprehensive
>   OCR software for creating editable and
>   searchable files from scanned
>   documents, PDFs and digital camera
>   images.
>
> ABBYY continues to lead in the OCR
>   language support. With FineReader 10,
>   users can process documents in **186
>   languages** including Chinese,
>   Japanese, Korean, Thai, **Hebrew**,
>   Armenian, Cyrillic, Greek, and Latin.
>   FineReader 10 also reads scripting
>   languages and simple chemical
>   formulas. The text recognition
>   software includes dictionaries with
>   spell-checking capabilities for 39
>   languages allowing verification of
>   recognized text directly in the
>   FineReader Editor.

Answer (score 1):

There is an opensource project named hocr aimed to provide free Hebrew OCR. It might be what you are looking to.
http://hocr.berlios.de/

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

the abbey finereader is your best bet I have been looking for some time to find a ocr program that reads Hebrew and this one is the the best so far, try it you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language -- in my case, Japanese.  If you have Microsoft Office 2007(and newer probably), you can add language packs (sometimes costs ~$30?) and use the Microsoft Document Imaging feature.  Microsoft appears to have Hebrew available as well.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/language/

However, I couldn't get it do anything other then crash, so I used SmartOCR Lite, which worked beautifully for Japanese.  I'm not sure if the SmartOCR I used is the same as the one Stella used, though.